# Unexpected result in WHERE clause on AI ID field

Tags: mysql, sql, orm

I have a table which's name is `users` in my MySQL database, and I am using this DB with Ruby on Rails application with ORM structure for years. The table has id field and this field is configured as AI (auto-increment), BIGINT.

Example of my users table;

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | John    |
|  2 | Tommy   |
|  3 | ...     |
|  4 | ...     |
|  5 | ...     |
|  6 | ...     |
+----+---------+
```

The problem I am facing is when I execute the following query I get unexpected rows.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1AW3F4SEFR';
```

This query is returning the exact same value with the following query,

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

I do not know why SQL let me use strings in WHERE clause on a data type INT. And as we can see from the example, my DB converts the strings I gave to the integer at position 0. I mean, I search for `1AW3F4SEFR` and I expect not to get any result. But SQL statement returns the results for id = `1`.

In Oracle SQL, the behavior of this exact same query is completely different. So, I believe there is something different on MySQL. But I am not sure about what causes this.

Comment: When you compare a string with a number, it automatically casts the string to a number before comparing.

Comment: If the string begins with a number, converting it to a number returns that initial number.

Comment: So `'123abc'` becomes `123`.

Comment: ...if you're using MySQL. Other databases raise an error, or cast the integer as string.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I always considered this a flaw in MySQL. But you shouldn't compare a numeric value with a string anyway in my opinion. If the column is numeric, compare it with a number. And no, if you compare the number with a string, MySQL applies this weird conversion. AFAIK there is no way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I would even go so far to call it a bug. Because it also allows completely invalid SQL like `where 'bla'`

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your opinions, I found a solution with the usage of CONCAT method in SQL. You can prevent this with basically adding the same string to id and the string you search for like below; `WHERE CONCAT('a',id) = CONCAT('a','1AW3F4SEFR')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been explained in the request comments, MySQL has a weird way of converting strings to numbers. It simply takes as much of a string from the left as is numeric and ignores the rest. If the string doesn't start with a number the conversion defaults to 0.

Examples: '123' => 123, '12.3' => 12.3, '.123' => 0.123, '12A3' => 12, 'A123' => 0, '.1A1.' => 0.1

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55cd18865fad4738d03bf28082217ca8

That MySQL doesn't raise an error here as other DBMS do, can easily lead to undesired query results that get a long time undetected.

The solution is easy though: Don't let this happen. Don't compare a numeric column with a string. If the ID '1AW3F4SEFR' is entered in some app, raise an error in the app or even prevent this value from being entered. When running the SQL query, make sure to pass a numeric value, so '1AW3F4SEFR' cannot even make it into the DBMS. (Look up how to use prepared statements and pass parameters of different types to the database system in your programming language.)

If for some reason you want to pass a string for the ID instead (I cannot think of any such reason though) and want to make your query fail-safe by not returning any row in case of an ID like '1AW3F4SEFR', check whether the ID string represents an integer value in the query. You can use `REGEXP` for this.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id AND @id REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Thus you only consider integer ID strings and still enable the DBMS to use an index when looking up the ID.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56f8ee902342752933c20b8762f14dbb

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanative answer, I have a table that is representing the values of a property in my app. Some of the values are the ID of those properties but some are not, so I basically checked the SQL table whether or not this specific row exists. If not, I wanted to display the ID itself. such like, you're entering a user's sex property but also the name of the user is stored in the same table (for some reason I needed to do it.). I query every property and if I can not find any result, I display the value itself (value itself is manually entered data). Hope you understand